# Life hacking site?

Tags: discussion, support, site-recommendation

A question on SO made me think of a question I have for Meta.

The question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21654069/memorizing-of-code

> This is more of a life hack question. How do you memorize big chunks
>   of code? Do you have any special techniques for that? Because right
>   now I have to remember about 1000 lines of code for daily uses, and I
>   thought that maybe some more experienced programmers will have a more
>   efficient way of remembering that.

Is there a Stack Exchange site that is or sort of is life hack oriented?

From Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life_hacking

> Life hacking refers to any productivity trick, shortcut, skill, or
>   novelty method to increase productivity and efficiency, in all walks
>   of life; in other words, anything that solves an everyday problem of a
>   person in a clever or non-obvious way.

If there is not, should there be?

Comment: Memorizing a lot of data doesn't sound like a life hack. There's nothing productive or efficient about memorizing big chunks of code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's a productivity site, which hosts [some questions on memorization](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/memory?sort=frequent). I wouldn't ask that question there as-is though; it lacks a plausible explanation for *why anyone would want to do that*. Don't get me wrong, there are good reasons to memorize specific techniques and even vast program architectures, but I'm skeptical that memorizing arbitrary 1000-line runs of code is worth anyone's time or effort outside of techo-thrillers. Presuming this task is motivated by an actual problem facing the asker, he should include at least a short mention of this in the question itself to avoid falling into [X-Y territory](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).

There have been a few different explicit Life Hacking proposals on Area51, but don't expect to see any of them grow into an actual *site* any time soon: the topic is untenably broad. There are experts on programming, experts on memorization, probably even experts on household chores... But finding an "expert on Life" is really too much to hope for.

Comment: I don't see any other sites mentioned here; [programmers.se] maybe?

Comment: psubsee linked to Productivity twice - the second link was to http://meta.productivity.stackexchange.com/questions/226/broadening-scope-lifehacking-questions

Comment: @AlienArrays it wasn't a perfectly fine answer, it was just a suggestion for Productivity.SE based on the help center's scope without any insight into the site itself.  Shog's answer covered that which made my answer redundant and not nearly as valuable, hence I deleted it.  If I thought it added something, I would have kept it

Answer (score 9):

[**Lifehacks Stack Exchange**](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/) is currently in [public beta](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64409/lifehacks).

However, it doesn't seem that your question would be a good fit there.

> Lifehacks is a place to ask about seemingly intractable, stubborn problems that need a bit of thinking "outside the box". If our question is…
>
> - seeking uncommon solutions to common problems;
> - asking for unusual ways of using everyday objects to achieve a certain task or solve a specific problem;
> - looking for simple and practical tips to life's everyday problems that may not have an obvious solution
>
> **and it is NOT about…**
>
> - conventional "how to…" questions about skills that can commonly be learned elsewhere;
> - using products in the way they were designed to be used (e.g. keyboard shortcuts, obscure features, how to get your smartphone to do {x});
> - **"mind hacks" including personal productivity & self-improvement tips, memorization & learning techniques, etc;**
> - contrived challenges that reject easy and readily available solutions simply to make the problem "more interesting"
>
> …then you are in the right place.
>
> Lifehacks SE is NOT a place to ask your everyday "how to…" questions. If your question amounts to learning a craft, or gaining some expertise in a skill you simply do not possess, your question may not be on topic here.

(emphasis mine)